# DBCursor hasNext seems to only return 1 result when it should return 2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I have the following...

```
DBCollection dbc = test.getCollection();
double count = dbc.count();
DBCursor cursor = dbc.find();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if( cursor.hasNext() )
  sb.append(cursor.next().toString());
```

This outputs only one record but shows a count of 2. This one seems to work...

```
DBCollection dbc = test.getCollection();
double count = dbc.count();
DBCursor cursor = dbc.find();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(double i = 0.0; i<count; i++)
  sb.append(cursor.next().toString());
```

What am I missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean to use

```
while( cursor.hasNext() )
    sb.append(cursor.next().toString());
```

Right now, you use 'if' but you probably want 'while'.